# How to set flag for an item in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I have a [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) which contains two columns and some rows. I would like to set a flag so that if an item in the second column is either a zero or empty, it cannot be edited. If the item clicked is not numeric, it will be shown with a red text.

My code:

```
def qtree_check_item(self, item, column):
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    if column == 1:
        if item.text(1) != '0':
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        if not item.text(1).isnumeric():
            item.setForeground(1, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))
```

This works if the item is zero. If I replace:

```
if item.text(1) != '0':
```

with

```
if item.text(1) != '':
```

This works for empty strings. But if I combine both using:

```
if item.text(1) != '0' or item.text(1) != '':
```

The flags are not set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need `and` rather than `or`.

Comment: @G.M. - That works...do you know why `and` is required in this case as I assumed `or` would have been more logical? Also please post your _comment_ as an **answer** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to set a flag so that if an item in the second column is
>   either a zero or empty, it cannot be edited.

You then have...

```
if item.text(1) != '0' or item.text(1) != '':
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

Now consider what happens if `item.text(1) == '0'`.  In that case the second test `item.text(1) != ''` passes and the conditional as a whole passes due to the `or`.  Likewise if `item.text(1) == ''` is true then the test `item.text(1) != '0'` will pass and the entire conditional pass as a result.

So, you only want to set the `editable` flag if both...

```
item.text(1) != '0' and item.text(1) != ''
```

hold true.

To put it another way, since `item.text(1)` cannot be equal to both `'0'` and `''` at the same time the conditional...

```
if item.text(1) != '0' or item.text(1) != '':
```

is essentially...

```
if True or False:
```

which will always pass.

(Sorry if that all seems a bit convoluted.)

Comment: No need to apologise, your answer makes a lot of sense. I forgot about the conditional being `True` if either statement is passed. Thank you =)